# Windows Update KB4284835 Freezing computers

Tags: windows, windows-update, freeze, windows-10-v1803

've been trying to update a work laptop which specs are

I5-4200M 2.5ghz 4GB Ram OS is Windows 10 Pro 64bit

I've been trying to update a machine it's 2018-06 Cumulative Update for Windows 10 Version 1803 KB4284835, the new OS build of 17134.112 from 17134.48. However it's been freezing up. Now Windows update won't even locate the update saying "You are up to date" when I try to run the individually downloaded stand alone updater it says this update is not applicable to my machine. So I ran the updates through Powershell and the issue still persists. Only through Powershell it's showing as Downloaded, what's even more weird is it's showing as an 85 GB update.

I've burned it to a disc, tried running the update. Freezes or says not applicable.

Ran it from the stand alone, same thing happens.

Windows Update is no longer finding it.

Powershell is showing it available and downloaded, but unable to be installed as it freezes upon installation. Locks up the whole computer, forcing a hard restart.

What can I do to get this updated? I saw Windows had released a "quick fix" of WinKey + Ctrl + Shift + B to restart the graphic drivers, but that's not even been working. Either it doesn't work at all it's that frozen, or it just turns off the screen and goes black and stays black.

Any suggestions or anyone else? I've been pouring through forums and Reddit and other places and everyone seems to be having major issues with the 1803 updates the past few months.

EDIT:

Currently the machine is running 17134.48

The updating stand alone is the defaulted Microsoft Windows Update Standalone Installer trying to install 2018-06 Cumulative Update for Windows 10 Version 1803 KB4284835

Comment: It does not matter which device as we have numerous devices here in the office trying to download/install the same update and it's causing all of them to Freeze.

Comment: Post a link to uploaded WindowsUpdates.log and/or msinfo32.exe saved result

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/hkgbev5r1vuf53e/WindowsUpdate.log?dl=0

Comment: What is the filename of the standalone installer for the patch in question?  Are you at this point running 17134.112  or 17134.48?  Please edit your question and provide the necessary clarification.

Comment: EDIT:

Currently the machine is running 17134.48 

The updating stand alone is the defaulted Microsoft Windows Update Standalone Installer trying to install 2018-06 Cumulative Update for Windows 10 Version 1803 KB4284835

Comment: See this page....https://windowsreport.com/kb4284835-issues/

Comment: Suspicious GoDaddy site "atapp04.internal.atsclock.com" for Windowsupdates suggests to me a hijacked service.  try Update this https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/954960/some-computers-do-not-receive-updates-from-the-wsus-server  Others have fixed using https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2734608/an-update-for-windows-server-update-services-3-0-service-pack-2-is-ava

Comment: What do you mean a hijacked service???

Comment: Service going to non-MS registered site for win updates

Comment: Others have fixed using https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2734608 so I posted that

Comment: I'll attempt that Server update as that is our WSUS. So I will let you know how that goes. It looks promising even when I'm not seeing an update for that server.

Comment: Although, I'm curious since the update is already downloaded on the PC. That's where the issue is coming from, the installation, not the download. Although maybe it's installing from the WSUS rather than just downloading regularly.

Comment: The log indicates your WSUS * atsclock.com, which I thought was suspicious ;) is   missing extended metadata, which we did not know.  Contact your IT admin if in doubt

Comment: @Damien I wanted to know the exact filename.  I already know the name of the update.

Comment: What line in the log? So I can show my boss. I'm just the help desk guy, low end of the totem pole here.

Comment: I talked to my boss, she's not convinced that the server is going elsewhere for an update as stated by Tony.

Comment: Also our server is running ver 6.3.9600.18838 so we are up to date on that

Answer (score 0):

Open CMD -> winver

(Should read “Version 1803 (OS Build 17134.112)” if it doesn’t continue through the steps

Disk Cleanup -> System Cleanup -> All

Download Update KB4284835, should be 490.3 MB
(2018-06 Delta Update for Windows 10 Version 1803 for x64-based Systems (KB4284835))

CMD(Must run as admin) -> Net Stop wuauserv

Run Update Manually through stand alone installer

Restart---Wait for Update to apply

Check Windows Update through Settings, it may be labelled as “Waiting to Install” click install and it will refresh itself seeing that the update has installed.

Open CMD -> winver

NOW it should read “Version 1803 (OS Build 17134.112)”

When following these steps I managed to get the update to go through on multiple work stations. If I just run the installer by itself, it freezes up about 1/4th of the way through if that. But thank you to everyone who helped. It is much appreciated.